# Why Data are not storing in file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling

I am trying to store tweet's labels in a file, simultaneously I print these labels on terminal and It works fine but the labels are not storing in file.

Here is my code...

```
import requests
import json

username = "****"
password = "****"

def start():
    header = { 'Content-Type':'application/json',}

    parameters = {
        ('version','2017-02-27'),
    }

    url = 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/analyze'

    tw = open('/home/darkhorse/Desktop/ML/refine_tweets.csv','r')
    labeling = open('/home/darkhorse/Desktop/ML/tweets_label.csv','w')
    for tweet in tw:
        Data = { "text":tweet,"features":{ "sentiment":{"document":True } } }
        # changing Data dict to str form
        Data = json.dumps(Data)

        r = requests.post(url, headers=header, params=parameters, data=Data, auth=(username, password))

        # r.content is a byte object so there is need to change it into str
        str_obj =r.content.decode("utf-8")

        # changing str to python obj dict.
        py_obj = json.loads(str_obj)

        try:
            print(py_obj["sentiment"]["document"]["label"])
            labeling.write(py_obj["sentiment"]["document"]["label"])
            labeling.write('\n')
        except:
            print('error')
            # labeling.write('error\n')

    labeling.close()
    tw.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

Here are top 12 tweets and their labels are..

```
1. AreEnglishbacktoplayingtheiroldbrandofcricket, neutral
2. Match6:After43.0Ov,England250/6.JosButtler28(25b),AdilRashid4(7b), neutral
3. Yesurright....wecan'thopeatall\r, neutral
4. BlowtotheUmmah., negative
5. VeryimpressivesideNewZealand, neutral
6. ENGvsNZ|CT2017|Overs43|ENG250-6|Buttler28*Rashid4*|Bowler:Southee112411\n, neutral
7. WhyisEnglandhosting, neutral
8. Latest:2\ufe0f\u20e35\ufe0f\u20e30\ufe0f\u20e3up250/6after43oversv, error
9. 250upforEnglandwithdrizzlearoundafter43overs, neutral
10. , error
11. Latest:2\ufe0f\u20e35\ufe0f\u20e30\ufe0f\u20e3up250/6after43oversv, error
12. Match6:JosButtlerhitsTimSoutheefora4!248/6(42.4Ov), neutral
```

Why labels are not storing in file?

Or you can guide me, any other method for storing them.

Comment: try using python with keyword to open file. And also csv library for csv read and write operation

Comment: You're only writing to the file if no exception occurs... so `py_obj["sentiment"]["document"]["label"]` is causing an error and you're masking exactly what that error is by your blanket `except` clause and displaying a rather vague and unhelpful `error` instead. Check what `py_obj` is by printing it and see if it's what you expect, remove your `try/except` for the moment and correct the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use library [facebook-sdk](https://www.google.com.eg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiD94v5o8LUAhUHChoKHUKOCAwQFggsMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpypi.python.org%2Fpypi%2Ffacebook-sdk&usg=AFQjCNE7_ul-1p9IRR22TeL85i5m_1RC9g).
It will enable you to do what you want within facebook